# Stripe Payment Link

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-9

how is it going?
I just built a payment link with Stripe and Laravel 9. I would like to know how do I know when a user succeeded with a stripe payment link?

I already built an enroll method in the controller and it works great, now I just want to redirect the user to the stripe payment page and if succeeded then finish the enrollment and let them use the class.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can either [use your Dashboard](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#track-payments) or [set up a webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links/api#tracking-payments) to listen for `checkout.session.completed` events.